# Xcode Server - Timed out trying to set AX messaging timeout

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-server

While performing integration with Xcode Server everything is fine but it makes a warning for every of my projects:

[image]

Why?

[image]

Comment: if you go to the Logs -> and then choose integration log are there errors associated with this?

Comment: @bolnad, I did update a question with error logs.

Comment: Not much help there, have you checked the Apple forums? Might be a bug

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on MacMini (El Capitan) with XCode Server. On the other MacBook without XCode Server everything worked fine.

I've uninstalled the XCode Server from the machine and AX messaging stopped timing out on my 'jenkins' account.